# Numpy stack with unequal shapes

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I've noticed that the solution to [combining 2D arrays to 3D arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18595488/combining-2d-arrays-to-3d-arrays) through `np.stack`, `np.dstack`, or simply passing a list of arrays only works when the arrays have same `.shape[0]`.

For instance, say I have:

```
print(arr)
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
```

it easy easy to get to:

```
print(np.array([arr[2:4], arr[3:5]])) # same shape
[[[4 5]
  [6 7]]

 [[6 7]
  [8 9]]]
```

However, if I pass a list of arrays of unequal length, I get:

```
print(np.array([arr[:2], arr[:3]]))
[array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3]])
 array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5]])]
```

How can I get to simply:

```
[[[0, 1]
  [2, 3]]
 [[0, 1]
  [2, 3]
  [4, 5]]]
```

What I've tried: a number of other [Array manipulation routines](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-manipulation.html).

Note: ultimately want to do this for more than 2 arrays, so `np.append` is probably not ideal.

Comment: What exactly do you expect? Array of lists? List of lists? A *regular* array isn't possible because of the unequal shapes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Numpy arrays have to be rectangular, so what you are trying to get is not possible with a numpy array.

You need a different data structure. Which one is suitable depends on what you want to do with that data.

Answer (score 3):

The function [`np.stack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.stack.html) joins multiple arrays along a new axis, not an existing one.  See:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array(range(10)).reshape((5,2))
>>> print arr
[[0 1]
 [2 3]
 [4 5]
 [6 7]
 [8 9]]
>>> t1 = np.array([arr[2:4], arr[3:5]])
>>> print t1.shape
(2, 2, 2)
```

It's not creating a new array of shape `(4,2)` which I think you're intending.  Look at [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) for that.

Note if you really want to use stack, the docs require all input arrays be the same shape:

> Parameters:    arrays : sequence of array_like Each array must have the
>   same shape.

So what you're doing is going to have undefined behavior.

**EDIT:** I read too quickly.  You are trying to add an axis.  Still, you can't pass uneven shapes to stack.  You would have to pad them all the the same shape.  Example:

```
arr = np.array(range(10)).reshape((5,2))
print arr
arr_p1 = np.zeros(arr[0:3].shape)
arr_p1_src = arr[0:2]
arr_p1[:arr_p1_src.shape[0],:arr_p1_src.shape[1]] = arr_p1_src
t2 = np.array([arr_p1, arr[0:3]])
print t2
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.  1.]
  [ 2.  3.]
  [ 0.  0.]]

 [[ 0.  1.]
  [ 2.  3.]
  [ 4.  5.]]]
```

Answer (score 3):

I've made a function that works for this problem, assuming that you are willing to pad to make the shape rectangular, and you have arbitrarily higher multidimensional arrays. It could probably be optimised further, but it's not too bad.

```
import numpy as np
def stack_uneven(arrays, fill_value=0.):
    '''
    Fits arrays into a single numpy array, even if they are
    different sizes. `fill_value` is the default value.

    Args:
            arrays: list of np arrays of various sizes
                (must be same rank, but not necessarily same size)
            fill_value (float, optional):

    Returns:
            np.ndarray
    '''
    sizes = [a.shape for a in arrays]
    max_sizes = np.max(list(zip(*sizes)), -1)
    # The resultant array has stacked on the first dimension
    result = np.full((len(arrays),) + tuple(max_sizes), fill_value)
    for i, a in enumerate(arrays):
      # The shape of this array `a`, turned into slices
      slices = tuple(slice(0,s) for s in sizes[i])
      # Overwrite a block slice of `result` with this array `a`
      result[i][slices] = a
    return result
```

The only caveat to using this is that the input must able to be treated a sequence of numpy arrays. So for your example of

```
arr = np.array([[0, 1],
                [2, 3],
                [4, 5],
                [6, 7],
                [8, 9]])
stack_uneven([arr[:2], arr[:3]], 0)
```

This would give you

```
array([[[0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [0, 0]],

   [[0, 1],
    [2, 3],
    [4, 5]]])
```

But this works equally for higher dimensional things, like:

```
arr = [np.ones([3, 2, 2]), np.ones([2, 3, 2]), np.ones([2, 2, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually np.vstack or np.hstack can be useful, if you vertical or horizontal stack is enough for you and you have at least one equal dimension.