# Why Can't Numpy Produce an Array from a List of Numpy Arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy

I'm writing some code to group vectors by the angles between them. For example I might have an array of vectors:

```
vectors = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2]])
```

With an acceptable angle deviation of 0.1 radians for example. Currently, I'm doing this in a while loop like so:

```
groups = []
while not vectors.size == 0:
    vector = vectors[0]
    angles = (vectors @ vector)/(np.linalg.norm(vector, axis=1))
    angles = np.arccos(angles/np.linalg.norm(vector))
    group = vectors[angles <= angle]
    groups.append(group)
    vectors = vectors[angles > angle]
return np.array(groups)
```

I expect this to return a numpy array with the following form:

```
expected_array = np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 2]]])
```

But instead I get the following:

```
actual_array = np.array([array([[1. , 0. , 0. ], [1.1, 0. , 0. ]]),
                         array([[0. , 2, 2]])])
```

Why doesn't Numpy notice that the list contains arrays and give me what I expect? Is there a way of making Numpy notice this? Or do you always have to use np.concatenate or something similar to get the desired result?

Comment: Does it really make a difference between the array or the list?  Is there something you can't do as a result of this?

Comment: It looks like a list of arrays may be the most appropriate data structure for your use case. Your desired output seems to discard the grouping information that was the entire purpose of the code.

Comment: `np.array` can't read your mind`  The problem is with your expectations.  But `np.vstack(groups)` might do what you want.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think you may be right actually, but I'm still interested in how to achieve the desired result. If only to know how to do it in the future. It doesn't really destroy my grouping per say, it just makes it harder to use the arrays, but perhaps with the added bonus of speed?

Comment: @Chris For a small use case no, it makes no difference and may actually be beneficial. But I guess I'm thinking if I have millions of vectors, would a returned array of the form I have specified be faster for future computations. Say for example vectored comparisons.

Comment: @hpaulj Yes, I'm trying to use that currently and struggling, any chance you would offer an answer, happy to accept even if the only answer to the question above is: "it just doesn't, okay?"

Answer (score 1):

"I expect this to return a numpy array with the following form:"

```
In [420]: np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 2]]])
<ipython-input-420-a1f3305ab5c3>:1: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray. np.array([[[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 2]]])

Out[420]: array([list([[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]]), list([[0, 2, 2]])], dtype=object)
```

Is that really what you expected?  An array that preserves the nesting of the lists?

`vstack` (or `concatenate`) can join the lists/arrays with the lists, to make a 2d array:

```
In [421]: np.vstack([[[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 2]]])
Out[421]: 
array([[1. , 0. , 0. ],
       [1.1, 0. , 0. ],
       [0. , 2. , 2. ]])
```

**this is the only version that can be used in fast compiled methods**.  Object dtype arrays use python speed iteration on the elements when doing calculations.  Computationally there's little advantage to creating a 'ragged' array.

Converting those 2 arrays back to lists:

```
In [422]: _420.tolist()
Out[422]: [[[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0]], [[0, 2, 2]]]
In [423]: _421.tolist()
Out[423]: [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [1.1, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 2.0, 2.0]]
```

The first has 3 levels of nesting, same as the original; the second has only 2.

===

Your code isn't runnable:

```
In [424]: vectors = np.array([[1, 0, 0], [1.1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 2]])
In [425]: groups = []
     ...: while not vectors.size == 0:
     ...:     vector = vectors[0]
     ...:     angles = (vectors @ vector)/(np.linalg.norm(vector, axis=1))
     ...:     angles = np.arccos(angles/np.linalg.norm(vector))
     ...:     group = vectors[angles <= angle]
     ...:     groups.append(group)
     ...:     vectors = vectors[angles > angle]
     ...: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-425-e50fafbda1c3>", line 4, in <module>
    angles = (vectors @ vector)/(np.linalg.norm(vector, axis=1))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in norm
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2561, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I was hoping to see the list `groups`, before you tried to make an array from it.  I don't feel like debugging your sample.

Answer (score 0):

In short: **It can!** *(But not in the way you want.)*

A search around this topic finds this question: [Numpy stack with unequal shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44951624/numpy-stack-with-unequal-shapes)

In which the following is made clear: **numpy arrays must be rectangular**, as the above example won't produce a rectangular array when added together this doesn't work.

If you try and do the same thing with **arrays of the same size** it **will work**. For example:

```
array = np.array([np.array([1, 2, 3]), np.array([1, 0, 1]))
```

Will produce an array with the shape (2, 3).

However, with arrays of different sizes the numpy array dtype defaults to the `object`, and all the individual arrays get stored instead.